# Code for a reactive table to plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to shiny, and I am trying to do a simple density plot where there are 2 groups of data, with reactive 'shifts' in the mean etc. 
A simplified summary of this is that one set of data has a mean of 0, and variance of 1. The second set of data has a mean of `shift`, which is defined in a slider.

I have tried to use `reactiveValues`, as shown in the code below to store the matrix of observations `d1`, generated from the `density` function y values,  and the corresponding x values are stored in  `x`.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("shift",
                     "shift of 2nd set",
                     min = -1,
                     max = 1,
                     value = 0)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   data <- reactiveValues({

     d1 <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=512)
     for(i in 1:70){
       d1[i,] <- density(rnorm(1000),from = -3, to = 3)$y
     }
     for(i in 71:100){
       d1[i,] <- density(rnorm(1000, input$shift),from = -3, to = 3)$y
     }
     x <- density(rnorm(1000),from = -3, to = 3)$x

   })
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      matplot(data$x, t(data$d1), type = "l", lty = 1, col = c(rep(1,70),rep(2,30)))
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above code is largely from the example shiny app, so please excuse any generic references. It *should* still work.

I was expecting a shiny plot with a slider on the left, and a plot on the right with 100 density lines in 2 colours. When the `shift` slider is changed the second set of data (red) will slide left or right depending on the shift.

Instead, I get the error message

```
  55: stop
  54: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  53: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
  52: $.reactivevalues
  47: server [/beavis/Documents/test/app.R#37]
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Is anyone able to help me fix this code? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Having played around for an hour I believe the issue lies in the `reactiveValues` section, but nothing so far has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice try. You're quite close. What you're missing is two things. You are creating a `data` object, which becomes reactive (I use `reactive` instead). This means that whenever you are calling `data`, you need to call it as `data()`.

Second, your `data` returns only `x`. Output of this reactive environment should in your case be a list of `x` and `d1`.

[image]

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("shift",
                  "shift of 2nd set",
                  min = -1,
                  max = 1,
                  value = 0, 
                  step = 0.1)  # I added a step
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  # This reactive environment can be accessed using data().
  data <- reactive({
    d1 <- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=512)
    for(i in 1:70){
      d1[i,] <- density(rnorm(1000),from = -3, to = 3)$y
    }
    for(i in 71:100){
      d1[i,] <- density(rnorm(1000, input$shift),from = -3, to = 3)$y
    }
    x <- density(rnorm(1000), from = -3, to = 3)$x
    list(x = x, d1 = d1)  # make sure that all objects are returned
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    matplot(data()$x, t(data()$d1), type = "l", lty = 1, col = c(rep(1,70),rep(2,30)))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```